# Lookup Value Formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In EXCEL I want to write a query which can lookup and copy the value,
an example I have 2 tables

**Table 1**

```
Name 
A
B
C
```

**Table 2**

```
Name    Value
A        4
B        5
```

**Expected Result -**

```
Table 3

Name    Value
A        4
B        5
C        Not Found
```

I tried to write the query like this but didn't work -

```
=HLOOKUP([Name];Sheet2![Name];[Value];True)
```

Comment: When you say: `didn't work`, that doesn't tell us much. Are you getting an unexpected result? or are you getting an error?

Comment: @Zac i was getting er error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using `INDEX`/`MATCH`.

```
=INDEX(Table2[Value], MATCH([@Name], Table2[Name], 0))
```

You can wrap it in an `IFERROR` to get the text "Not Found".

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Table2[Value], MATCH([@Name], Table2[Name], 0)), "Not Found")
```

Comment: you are the best

Answer (score 1):

Try in Sheet3!A2: `=Sheet1!A2`

and in Sheet3!B2: `=VLOOKUP(A2;Sheet1!$A$2:$B$4;2;FALSE)`

For further reference: https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1